# How can I rev a "drive by wire" car from under the hood?

Tags: obd-ii, rpm, throttle

I've got a 2013 Hyundai Accent with a noise coming from somewhere under the hood. Happens only at a fairly narrow band of engine speed (1100-1200 RPM). I've been trying to hunt around for the source, but I'm running into an issue: Since this car has a drive-by-wire throttle, there's no obvious way for me to bring the engine up to the speed required to hear the noise.

On my other ('94) car, I can just grab the accelerator cable with my hand and goose the throttle to my heart's content. On this car, the throttle body is buried under a mass of plastic covers, sensors and servos, and I'm pretty sure that even if I did manage to manually move the throttle plate I'd just make the ECU angry.

So what's the solution? I don't have a helper to sit in the driver's seat and give it gas while I listen, and any methods involving the ODB port seem to involve a lot of reverse engineering and experimentation.

Answer (score 2):

Have a friend / relative help you.

Only suggested as "use a brick etc" is not safe and you have to make sure you get the electronics correct otherwise you can permanently damage the ecu.

Answer (score 1):

If you have wiring diagrams and you know how the throttle motor works (e.g. what voltages it expects), you could feed the ECM TPS signals and power/ground the motor with a variable resister.

You could also just put something on and under the pedal. Then play around until you get the desired RPM. Or just buy a pedal depressor.

Comment: "pedal depressor" -- great idea